# Can´t get google maps API key verified

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm trying to get an image created from Google Maps - instead of using google maps, i want to load an image of location instead where page will be loaded faster.

I found this service http://staticmapmaker.com/google/

Now I'm trying to enter my google api key which I have created (Browser Key) 
wit this code:

```
<img width="600" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Albany,+NY&zoom=13&scale=false&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&key=keykeykeykeykey&format=gif&visual_refresh=true" alt="Google Map of Albany, NY">
```

Just replaced "keykeykeykey" with my Google API key but the error I´m getting is:

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 210.210.210.210, with referer: http://website.net/

Now i want everyone to access this image not only specific ip:s.. 
Can anyone else get this to work?

Comment: [It works for me. (fiddle, jsfiddle is grandfathered for keyless access, at least for now)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lyqf9bad/)  That implies your key is not correct or not enabled for the Static Maps API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate your Static Maps API key here:

[Google Developer Console - Static Maps API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend/)

Afterwards you will find your API key [here at the credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials). There you can check your configuration again and change the allowed HTTP referrers. If you use a * as placeholder or leave the field empty all referrers are allowed to use your key (and use your quota).